# How to get Front camera as default when clicks button

Tags: android

When clicking on a button I need to open the front camera by default but back camera is displaying. Please give me some idea how to open front camera.

Answer (score 2):

**Add this to the intent**

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

add these permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```